# Mongo shell connection failed after adding authentication of adminOfAnyDatabase

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-shell

```
root@ip-172-31-34-204:/tmp/asterisk-16.1.1# sudo mongod --repair
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1980 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-34-204
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.13
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: fbdef2ccc53e0fcc9afb570063633d992b2aae42
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-11T10:55:19.993+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { repair: true }
2020-02-11T10:55:19.997+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-02-11T10:55:19.997+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected WT journal files.  Running recovery from last checkpoint.
2020-02-11T10:55:19.997+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] journal to nojournal transition config: create,cache_size=1459M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2020-02-11T10:55:20.015+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1581418520:15471][1980:0x7fac126bad00], txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 1/0,  and the file is version 2/0: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-02-11T10:55:20.015+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1581418520:15533][1980:0x7fac126bad00], txn-recover: WiredTiger is unable to read the recovery log.
2020-02-11T10:55:20.015+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1581418520:15552][1980:0x7fac126bad00], txn-recover: This may be due to the log files being encrypted, being from an older version or due to corruption on disk
2020-02-11T10:55:20.015+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1581418520:15562][1980:0x7fac126bad00], txn-recover: You should confirm that you have opened the database with the correct options including all encryption and compression options
2020-02-11T10:55:20.015+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1581418520:15632][1980:0x7fac126bad00], txn-recover: Recovery failed: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2020-02-11T10:55:20.018+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28718:-31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 254
2020-02-11T10:55:20.018+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28718 -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error, terminating
2020-02-11T10:55:20.018+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-02-11T10:55:20.018+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2020-02-11T10:55:20.018+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2020-02-11T10:55:20.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-02-11T10:55:20.018+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Before this I've tried giving the account authentication: [How to secure MongoDB with username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881208/how-to-secure-mongodb-with-username-and-password) 
Can not connect to mongo also:

```
root@ip-172-31-34-204:/tmp/asterisk-16.1.1# mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.13
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2020-02-11T10:56:37.487+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-02-11T10:56:37.487+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: please share command of composing file if you are running mongo using docker.i am not sure but maybe your data or wiredTiger is corrupted.  http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/

Comment: Yes, I'm running it inside docker container. If my data or wiredTiger is corrupted then what steps should I follow next? @HarshManvar

Comment: Did you try to update the mongo version?

Comment: No I haven't done that

Comment: using which version of mongod ? If you have persistence volume can you try updating the version of mongo to the latest 3.6.3? Howerver there is also same scenario : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381581/upgrading-older-mongo-database-after-unintentional-mongo-version-upgrade